# Pandas still converts ints to float when I make a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

Pandas still makes ints into floats when I try to make a mixed-type series into a dictionary.

The suggested workarounds don't work for me. I've tried casting to object and using `iteritems`, and both together. I'm using pandas version 0.24.2

```
test_series = pd.Series([1,1.3])
result = [{index:value} for index,value in test_series.astype(object).iteritems()]
print (results)
```

Expected :

```
[{0: 1}, {1: 1.3}]
```

Actual :

```
[{0: 1.0}, {1: 1.3}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the function **is_integer()** to check if your float is an integer

```
test_series = pd.Series([int(1),1.3])
results = [{index:int(value)} if value.is_integer() else {index:value} for index,value in test_series.iteritems()]
print (results)
```

---

Out :

```
[{0: 1}, {1: 1.3}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using the [`modulo`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations) operator `%` and an `if-else` statement within your dict comprehension:

```
result = [{i: int(x)} if x % 1 == 0 else {i: x} for i, x in test_series.iteritems()]
```

[out]

```
[{0: 1}, {1: 1.3}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`is_integer`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#float.is_integer) method:

```
test_series = pd.Series([1,1.3])
result = [{k: int(v) if v.is_integer() else v for k,v in test_series.astype(object).items()}]
print (result)
[{0: 1, 1: 1.3}]
```